# How to get input type value from a table using php

Tags: php

**why $_POST['destination'] does not have a value?**
*Please Help*

How to get value from input type

```
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="day" placeholder="<?php echo $row['day']; ?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="destination" placeholder="<?php echo $row['destination']; ?>"></td>
        <td><a href="index24.php?delete=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger"> Edit </a></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>

//index24.php
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
if (isset($_GET['delete'])){
    $id = $_GET['delete'];
    $destination = $_POST['destination']; //why $_POST['destination'] does not have a value?
    $day = $_POST['day'];
    $query = "UPDATE tbl_itinerary SET destination = '$destination', day = '$day' WHERE id =  '" . $id . "'";
    mysqli_query($db,$query);
    header('location: index4.php');
}
```

Comment: destination input has no value attribute

Comment: Why are you mixing $_GET  and $_POST?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` , what do you get?

Comment: there is no form to retrieve post values

Answer (score 0):

Put values on input value="" attribute not in placeholder.

```
    <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="day" value="<?php echo $row['day']; ?>" placeholder=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="destination" value="<?php echo $row['destination']; ?>" placeholder=""></td>
    <td><a href="index24.php?delete=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger"> Edit </a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I already tried changing the placeholder to value but the inputted data is still empty. $destination = $_POST['destination']; //why $_POST['destination'] does not have a value and value is always empty?

Comment: I review your code once more time and found you are listing all product in a table using loop. In this condition, hypertext is send only a url "index24.php?delete=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" so you only get $_GET['delete']. You are not submit a form, you only redirect on page.

When you are using <form> tag and post a form then get values, USING POST and GET method.
Now you can use ajax function using onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

Don't echo out values in placeholder.
You can do it in this way:

`value="<?php echo $row['day']; ?>`

```
Not like this placeholder="<?php echo $row['day']; ?>"
```

“Placeholder is meant to show hints to the users what to type in the field”

**EDIT**

```
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="day" value="<?php echo $row['day']; ?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="destination" value="<?php echo $row['destination']; ?>"></td>
 <td><a href="index24.php?delete=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger"> Edit </a></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>

//index24.php
//covertion is important here

$id = intval($_GET['delete']);
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
//submit - would be the name of button in your <form> tag.

if (isset($_GET['submit'])){

$destination = $_POST['destination'];
$day = $_POST['day'];

$query = "UPDATE tbl_itinerary SET destination = '$destination', day = '$day' WHERE id =  '" . $id . "'";
   mysqli_query($db,$query);
   header('location: index4.php');
}
```

```
Maybe this will help you...
```

You were getting value of id as string. You need to convert it to int.

I would recommend you to use procedures to prevent sql injection.

Comment: I already tried changing the placeholder to value but the inputted data is still empty. $destination = $_POST['destination']; //why $_POST['destination'] does not have a value and value is always empty?

Comment: You're getting values from database or through your form? And why you're using both $_GET and $_POST?

Comment: I'm just showing the current data from my database and I want to get the new inputted data from my form in order to edit the data in my database. I'm using $_GET for the button to get a value from my database and $_POST to get the inputted value from the form

Comment: Check my edited answer, maybe that will help you...then mark it as your answer ...ty

Answer (score 0):

Looking at you code snippet, you can handle this scenario in following different ways :

1. `$_POST` is part of form handing, so if you need to use `$row['destination']` in a different page you need to have it added with in `<form>` tag and mention the page in 'action' attribute. Read [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)
2. Since you are using `$_GET` to get the `id` value in `index24.php` page you can query to get all the data with `WHERE` clause.
3. Use Ajax [Example](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=php%20to%20show%20data%20in%20table%20and%20edit#kpvalbx=_bMNUXp7GMIGE4-EPi4i4iAU40)